# Paste mode sometimes inserting "<Paste>"

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, macos

Sometimes when I paste (via cmd+v) some text into neovim, it inserts `<Paste>` at the bottom, i.e:

```
This
was pasted and
I got some bonus letters
<Paste>
```

I can't figure where this text comes from and googling it is impossible because I can't search for the actual tag, it just shows results for anything including "paste" and "inserts text" which is pretty common when talking about copy-paste...

Often it leaves me in `PASTE` mode afterwards too, which might be a clue.

I'm on OS X, iTerm2 with I guess the default `pbcopy/pbpaste` providers, perhaps its a bug with them?

Comment: Ive never seen this happen in terminal vim, and i use pbcopy/paste all the time (via `r !`, `”*`, and literal Command-V in paste mode). Probably specific to neovim/iterm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/7994) with Neovim.

The [suggested workaround](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/7994#issuecomment-388296360) until the problem is fixed is

```
au InsertLeave * set nopaste
```